(Godot 3.5 3D) i'm making a interaction system and i have a problem with the "Area" node
Version
Godot 3.5 (GDScript)
Issue
I'm making an interaction system (for example: open doors, disappear objects, etc.) and I want to make as if the character was doing those actions with his hands and for that I'm using an "Area" node to get the object's methods and so I can do the desired actions, and I've found that I don't know how to use correctly the "Area" node XD.
What i tried
here is the code:
extends Node

onready var interact_label = $"../UI_Debug/E"

onready var _input_node = $"../input_save_node"

func _on_Hands_area_body_entered(body: Node) -> void:
    if body.has_method("interact"):
        interact_label.visible = true
        
        if _input_node.interact_action:
            body.interact()
        
        
    else:
        interact_label.visible = false
    print("a, ", body)
        

I realized that the mistake I am making is that I am using the _on_Hands_area_body_entered(body: Node) signal as if it were a _process(delta) and I also realized that I can't call the function or assign the variable body to another one, and I wanted to know if there was any other way to make the interactions as if the character was using his hands.

Hello, this question is better suited to one of the more interactive discussion channels like the official discord and forums. You can always read about Area3D in the docs which has links to tutorials to follow.

I would raise a flag when _on_Hands_area_body_entered() is called to say that a body has entered, and then handle it all in a _process() method.  I'm not sure where/why you want to assign body to another one?
